# How to cast/convert a python function to std::function<double(double*)> in pybind11?

Tags: python, c++11, pybind11

I am using pybind11 to implement binds for my c++ project. 
So, my problem is basically how to define a python function in the interpreter
and call it from the C++ code. 
The C++ interface passes data using a pointer (double*) and I don't know how to code the function in the interpreter and how to convert it for a std::function to perform the evaluation:

```
// C++
//--------
double cpp_call( const std::array<double,N> &value, const std::function<double(double*)> &func) 
{
    return func(value.data());
}

// python binding with pybind11
// module definition... 
 ...
 m.def("py_call", &cpp_call);

//python interpreter 
//-------------------

?
```

Please, could someone give some tip to me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely missing a couple of requires headers to get this working, `#include <pybind11/functional.h>` (for the `std::function` support) and `#include <pybind11/stl.h>` (for the stl container support); neither header is included by default (to keep the core project smaller).

With those, your example almost works (it just needs a `const` added to the inner argument of the `std::function`, i.e. `const std::function<double(const double *)> &func`: the `std::array` is const and thus its `.data()` returns a const pointer).

Here's a full example showing this working:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/functional.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>

double cpp_call(const std::array<double, 3> &values,
                const std::function<double(double *)> &func) {
    double ret = 0;
    for (auto d : values) ret += func(&d);
    return ret;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(stack92, m) {
    m.def("sum", &cpp_call);
}
```

Python:

```
>>> import stack92
>>> def f(v): return v**.5
... 
>>> print("1+2+3 =", stack92.sum([1, 4, 9], f))
1+2+3 = 6.0
```